# Open Page inside iframe

Tags: asp.net, html, iframe

I have a application hosted in a dedicated server. I need the login page of the application to load inside a iframe. After user enters user name and password, user clicks on the login button and then gets redirected to the home page. Following is my code: (home page should also open inside iframe.)

```
<iframe id="top" style="width:790px; background-color:#e0effb; height:600px" frameborder="0" 
src="https://www.test.com/">

</iframe>
```

My issue is iframe opens the login page but after I click on the login button it gives me 404 error: Page not found. This problem occurs in IE but works fine in Chrome. My code for the login button click is:

```
Response.Redirect(ResolveUrl("~/Home.aspx"));
```

Comment: what the exactly url of the iframe when 404 error occurs?

Comment: /login.aspx.but login.aspx is not in the root.it's in ~/Account/Login/login.aspx